# How to run linter on PR in GitHub?

Tags: typescript, github, lint, tslint

Project is written in typescript. Pre-commit hooks are implemented with [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky). (They only work if husky is installed locally)

Is there a way to prevent merge of PR if lint error exists?

Comment: You need [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions), example [ESLint Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/eslint-action)

Comment: Another idea is to use [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/) which is easy to set up with GitHub.